Kafak produce arvo message success, but consumer deserialize EOFException
This topic has multiple produce, some messages cannot be processed, Most of the messages are being consumed normally.
pom info

<dependency>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-json-serializer</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

the exception information is as follows

2024-05-09 10:03:31.702 ERROR [main] - [SchemaConsumerTest.java:100] - Error deserializing key/value for partition xxxx.topic-3 at offset 480960. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition xxxx.topic-3 at offset 480960. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:331)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:283)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.fetchRecords(FetchCollector.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.collectFetch(FetchCollector.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:693)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:585)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:827)
    at com.citi.gsp.kafka.consumer.SchemaConsumerTest.receiveMsg(SchemaConsumerTest.java:92)
    at com.citi.gsp.kafka.consumer.SchemaConsumerTest.testConsumer(SchemaConsumerTest.java:83)
    at com.citi.gsp.kafka.consumer.SchemaConsumerTest.main(SchemaConsumerTest.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 13212
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:156)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:321)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:514)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:155)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:465)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:125)
    ... 16 common frames omitted


I checked the schema id 13212 and it looks fine, I did get the schema when debugging locally.
I use StringDeserializer to get this message to confirm that it is not an empty message

Are you sure xxxx.topic-3 at offset 480960 is actually Avro?

When I read it with StringDeserializer, it was garbled. It looked similar to other message formats. I remember that the schema id was read from the message. If it was not Arvo, there should be no schemaId.
